# SSIS 2008 and Undouble

Tags: ssis

I am using SSIS with SQL Server 2008 R2.  I am importing large-ish text files (approx 0.5 Gb), and these files use double quotes as a text qualifier, and the comma as a field delimiter.

Many of the files have text qualified fields and include a comma between the terminating double quotes.  SSIS should interpret this is a single field, (one that happens to contain a comma).  Instead, it interprets it as two different fields.

I can find plenty of workarounds for SQL 2005 - generally under the heading of "undouble" - but the only 2008 workarounds I can find require some complex programming.  Does anyone have any simple 2008 workarounds?

Much appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone with similar issues, see http://ssisdfs.codeplex.com/releases/view/32846.

The DFS 2008 download from codeplex is an absolute winner.

Comment: I'd vote this up but for the fact that the installer failed, the DLL doesn't contain the delimited file source, and the documentation doesn't exist. It's astounding that SSIS's Flat File Source doesn't support the CSV format. For me it's a show stopper. :(

Answer (score -1):

Use three double quotes instead of single double quotes for "Text Qualifier" in "Flat File Connection Manager Editor"... Simple!